# HERE Maps: change visibility of a cluster layer

Tags: here-api

Once a cluster is created and added to a map with this:

```
let layer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);
map.addLayer(layer);
```

How can one change the layer visibility (show/hide) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the removeLayer() method for that. For example:

> ```
> var handleClusterLayer = function(cb)
> {
>   if(cb.checked)
>   map.addLayer( clusterOverlayLayer );
>   else
>   map.removeLayer( clusterOverlayLayer );
> };
> ```